# Contact Form 7 Data to Whatsapp Link

Tags: redirect, plugin-contact-form-7

Is it possible to get the data from the user input in Contact Form 7 to a WhatsApp prefilled text link?

I'm trying to get the people who submitted the form to redirect to Whatsapp with the prefilled text as a summary of their input from the form. It's like an order confirmation via WhatsApp.

I am a newbie in website developing. I love to learn a lot from the community. Your kind reply is most appreciated.

Regards,
Afiq

Comment: Some info for you: Form Page > Thank You Page >Delay Redirect 3seconds to Whatsapp (I like to put the form input in the prefilled text here). The plugins I use are Contact Form 7 and Delay Redirect.

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy to achieve.  Basically you need to store your submitted data and make it available on your redirected page.

TO achieve this you can use the plugin [Post My CF7 Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/) which allows you to store the submitted data as a post (which can delete once the redirection is complete, or store the data for later reference) and then add the following to your functions.php file,

```
add_filter('cf7_2_post_form_append_output', 'redirect_on_submit', 10, 3);
function redirect_on_submit($script, $attr, $nonce){
  //$attr cf7 shortcode attributes to check if this is the correct form.
  $url = site_url('/submitted'); //page slug to redirect to.
  $url = add_query_arg( array('cf72post' => $nonce,), $url);
  $url = esc_url($url);
  $script .= '<script>'.PHP_EOL;
  $script .= 'document.addEventListener( "wpcf7mailsent", function( event ) {'.PHP_EOL;
  $script .= '  var save = document.getElementsByClassName("cf7_2_post_draft");'.PHP_EOL;
  $script .= '  if(save.length == 0  || "false" === save[0].value){'.PHP_EOL;
  $script .= '    location = "'.$url.'";'.PHP_EOL;
  $script .= '  }'.PHP_EOL;
  $script .= '}, false );'.PHP_EOL;
  $script .= '</script>'.PHP_EOL;
  return $script;
}
```

this will basically redirect your submitted form to your page URL defined on the first line (in this example '/submitted', so you can set that to whatever you want.

On the submitted page template, you can now access the saved post with the following function,

```
if(isset($_GET['cf72post'])){
  $post_id = get_transient($_GET['cf72post']);
  $cf7Post = get_post($post_id);
  $whatsapp_text = $cf7Post->post_content;
  echo '<p>The following message will be sent to WhatsApp in 3 seconds:</p>';
  echo '<p>'.$whatsapp_text.'</p>';
  echo '<form name="whatsappForm" action='/submitted'><input type="hidden" name="submitted-post-id" value="'.$post_id.'"/></form>';
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.onload=function(){ 
    window.setTimeout(function() { document.whatsappForm.submit(); }, 3000);
};</script>';
}else if(isset($_POST['submitted-post-id'])){
  //the page is now being reloaded after 3 secs and you have the original data submitted data saved as the post_id.
  $post_id = $_POST['submitted-post-id'];
  $cf7Post = get_post($post_id);
  $whatsapp_text = $cf7Post->post_content;
  //send your $whatsapp_text to your whatsapp link
  // delete your $cf7Post if you don't need it.
}
```

Comment: How to send your $whatsapp_text to your whatsapp link?